# How to completely remove bad words from console using bad word package in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

So recently i was trying to make a code that can completely remove bad words from console but it replaces with ****. How can i completely remove bad words from list?

```js
const Filter = require("bad-words");
const filter = new Filter();
const words = require("./extra-words.json");
filter.addWords(...words);
console.log(filter.clean("Don't be an ash0le"));
```

Comment: Do another loop to replace ***** with an empty string

Comment: Can you please help by answering i couldn't understand.

Comment: You should add the code for `Filter` to your question. Welcome to SO by the way. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [mcve]. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bad-words#placeholder-overrides), you can set empty string as the place holder and then [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the result.

```
const Filter = require('bad-words');
const customFilter = new Filter({ placeHolder: ''});
 
customFilter.clean("Don't be an ash0le").trim(); //Don't be an
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the package documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bad-words#placeholder-overrides
Instead of replacing with x, replace with empty string.